# Script runs fine in ISE but fails from Command Prompt

Tags: powershell, command-prompt

I have the following script:

```
Add-Computer -DomainName ("a.b.c.d") -Credential (New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential("a.b.c.d\abcdadmin", (ConvertTo-SecureString "1234qwer" -AsPlainText -Force)))
```

Obviously the domain is not 'a.b.c.d' but it follows that. It has no special characters or anything that would lead me to believe it would cause problems. From the ISE the output:

```
Add-Computer : Cannot add computer '<removed>' to domain 'a.b.c.d' because it is already in 
that domain.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-Computer -DomainName ("a.b.c.d") -Credential (New-Object System. ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (20012UA95009JZ:String) [Add-Computer], InvalidOperationExce 
   ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AddComputerToSameDomain,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddComputerCommand
```

So it clearly runs fine in the ISE (with the exception that it's already in the domain), but the Command Prompt says otherwise:

```
At line:1 char:143
+ ... fl.us\abcdadmin, (ConvertTo-SecureString 1234qwer -AsPlainText -Force)))
+                    ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordEx
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument
```

The biggest limitation is that the script must be one-line.

Comment: In case your password has a dollar sign, escape that string with single quotes instead of double. There might be variables set in ISE prior to this script running that change the behavior of string parser. Same with other strings, probably.

Comment: "The biggest limitation is that the script must be one-line."  Your final result maybe, but testing certainly doesn't.  Break it up into multiple lines with variables and see where it's breaking.

Comment: The password is *actually* 1234qwer
How would I do a multi-line script via command-prompt's 'Powershell' command?

Comment: Your second error does not match the code above. `... fl.us\abcdadmin,` I do not see closing quotes there. You might just have a parsing error.  How are you running this _command line_?